# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getters') in vuex in vue

Tags: vue.js, module, nuxt.js, vuex, store

I want to use a namespace in my Vuex module but I have the following error:
[image]

This is my store:

`banks.module.js`

```js
import ApiService from "@/core/services/api.service";

// action types
export const BANKS = "banks";
///mutations
export const SET_BANKS = "setBanks";
export const banks = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    banks: [],
  },

  getters: {
    banksget(state) {
      return state.banks;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    [BANKS](context) {
      return ApiService.get("api/bank").then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("auth request - bank:", data);
        context.commit(SET_BANKS, data);
      });
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    [SET_BANKS](state, banks) {
      state.banks = banks;
    },
  },
};
```

In my component's script section:

```js
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { BANKS } from "@/core/services/store/banks.module";

beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch(`banks/${BANKS}`);
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    banks: "banks/banksget",
  }),
},
```

I dont know where is my mistakes but I get this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getters')

Comment: Does it work if you do `this.$store.getters['banks/banksget']()` instead of `mapGetters`?

Comment: @kolaente no doesnt work

Comment: What about `...mapGetters('banks', { banks: 'banksget' })`?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `getters` for `banks` because you are calling the data directly without applying any operation. `mapState` is more suitable here.